# Installing Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7 (x64).

The problem in brief is; when I do this the installer says it will be installed in the "x86" folder, but also displays this message:

```
Setup will install the following components:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 64bit prerequisites (x64)
..... etc
```

My question is,

1 - Will VS be installed as 64-bit or 32-bit?

2 - Is this normal or there is another version of Visual Studio that would be installed in the 64-bit folder?

Comment: May I ask you to show some code?

Comment: @SargeBorsch What code is it that you're hoping will be relevant to his question?

Comment: @JBentley An attempt to solve a programming problem, maybe

Comment: @SargeBorsch His question is about programming tools, not about a programming problem, so I don't see how showing code would have any relevance at all. Stackoverflow isn't only for problems which involve code. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); specifically, *"if your question generally covers [...] software tools commonly used by programmers [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"*

Comment: @JBentley Oops, okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know for Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 (both 64 bit installs in my case) it installs in both x86 and normal (64 bit) Program Files folders. Only a few things will be in the 64 bit folder, some IDE and Packages stuff (only IDE for 2008, probably same for 2005). Most of the install is indeed in the x86 folder.

Answer (score 0):

It will be fine. VS itself is a 32-bit application (ref: [64-bit Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).